# How to put a date watermarker in android camera activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

I'm getting pictures with the next code:

```
public void foto(View v) {
    nom_foto = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ aptr.ruta_temp + cuadrilla + "/" + medidor + "_"+ cont_foto + ".jpg";
    File arch = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ aptr.ruta_temp+ cuadrilla);
    if (!arch.exists())
        arch.mkdirs();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    int code = TAKE_PICTURE;
    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(nom_foto));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(intent, code);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.minifoto);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                private MediaScannerConnection msc = null;
                {
                    msc = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this);
                    msc.connect();
                }
                public void onMediaScannerConnected() {msc.scanFile(nom_foto,null); 
                }
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
            { msc.disconnect();}};
        Toast.makeText(usuario_lectura.this,"Foto N° " + cont_foto + " agregada  correctamente",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cont_foto++;
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nom_foto));
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        File file = new File(nom_foto);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works properly, the picture has taken correctly and saved on the SD card... But, I have to add a watermarker, including the date... How can I add it?, the camera activity doesn't give me these option...

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a textual or graphical watermark to your image from the camera, you must open the image, edit it in a `Canvas` with `Paint/Graphics` overlays, then re-encode it as a .jpg image, and re-save it as a file on the SD card. You can save over the original file from the camera. All of these steps are fairly straightforward.

There is, however, a serious hurdle.

Most devices will not be able to open the full-size image from the camera in a single Bitmap. There is not enough heap memory available. Therefore, you will have to use a scale factor `inSampleSize` to open your image. Thus, the watermarked image will be forever smaller by some factor than the original from the camera.

I do not think there is any way around this issue :(

Comment: I think that this is the best way to do it, I'll try to do it using Canvas, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept (check) and upvote (triangle) any correct answers.